# can countdown work simultaneously with the program in c++

Tags: c++

I am currently making a quiz program. And I created a countdown, but as c++ does actions line by line I am getting what I want. I want countdown work simultaneously with the tests.

here is the one part of my program

```
void QUIZ::OOP2()
{
system("cls");
QUIZ("OOP2");
int oop2_time = 100;
for (int i = oop2_time; oop2_time >= 0; i--)
{
cout << "\t\t\tQuestions of OOP2\n\n";
line();
cout << "1. Switch selection structure can be used to represent any kind of if-else selection structure? \n";
line();
cout << " a) True b) False \n";

CorrectB(var);
if (oop2_time == 100)
{
cout << "You have the remaining" << oop2_time << "seconds \n" << endl;
Sleep(40000);
}
if (oop2_time == 60)
{
cout << "You have the remaining" << oop2_time << "seconds \n" << endl;
Sleep(30000);
}
if (oop2_time == 30)
{
cout << "You have the remaining" << oop2_time << "seconds \n" << endl;
Sleep(15000);
}
if (oop2_time == 15)
{
cout << "You have the remaining" << oop2_time << "seconds \n" << endl;
Sleep(10000);
}
if (oop2_time == 5)
{
cout << "You have the remaining" << oop2_time << "seconds \n" << endl;
Sleep(5000);
cout << "\nTime is out\n";
goback();
intro();
}

result("OOP2");
goback();
}
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for a way to wait for user input and display time countdown at the same time, you might want to take a look at multi-threading.
Have a look at multi-threading on C++ Reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/). Basically, you need to create 2 threads, one that waits for the user input and one that displays the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

Without using multi-threading or std::chrono but just your base code, here's a code snippet. I have used recursive function and a time resolution of 1 second. The countdown can also be terminated prematurely in the main by setting `stop = true;` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void wait(double sec, bool& stop)
{
    std::cout <<"Time remaining "<< sec << " sec\n";
    if (stop || sec <= 0) return;
    Sleep(1000);
    wait(sec-1, stop);
}


int main()
{
    bool stop = false;
    wait(5, stop);
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for -- no need to use platform specific apis or threads.

Comment: anyway compiler is not compiling simultaneously. it is showing time remaining 100,time remaining 99,time remaining 98,time remaining 97 before displaying tests